# Website DLL Access Denied

Tags: visual-studio-2010, access-denied, activereports

I just recently inherited a website and while there are errors in the build (its missing `import Microsoft.VisualBasic` in a few places and i have fixed these)

There was no solution files with this website so i have just added my own and imported the website,

what i am finding now is that when i build the website i get

```
Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'ActiveReports.Chart, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
```

I know its not a permissions issue as i have gone in and edited the permissions to allow for everyone to access the file.

I am working on a Windows 7 x64 machine, but if i look at the DLL its targeted towards a x86 build, could this be causing the problem OR could it be that i have copied the files across from a dev server to my local machine.

I have tried to google it and most of the results are showing as permissions to the file.

any help you could give me would be great.

Thanks

**Update**
After some more investigation i found this in the web.config of the project
`<identity impersonate="true" password="yyy" userName="xxx" />`
and the Bin folder was trying to connect using this user.
hence the Permissions as the user was not valid on my machine

I have now learned a very big lesson, always validate the Web.Config of a website you inherit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me the DLLs needed to be added to the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that the reference to this DLL in your project is to this same version and not a different version?

Comment: Yes the versions do match exactly

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the ActiveReports.Chart assembly to your project and you should be good to go. In case you are facing any issues then just send us an email to powersupport@grapecity.com